# Can I get the branch of phone if it sends a message or make a call to me?

Tags: mobile

I want to know the branch of the phone,such as  Samsung，htc,moto,iphone,etc

I just want to know if somebody send me a message or call me,can I get which brand of mobile phone he used ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. I would write more, but there's nothing more to write.

Comment: I just want to know if I can do this, nothing else ....